# XMLHttpRequest cross site scripting on same server but different port

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

using XMLHttpRequest it is not possible to open a connection to a document on a different domain than where the page itself is hosted.

but what about different ports?

for example I have a webserver running on my machine listening on port 80 so the webaddress would look like this:

```
http://localhost:80/mypage.html
```

and I have another webserver running on localhost which is meant to process the ajax requests but listens on a different port. so the javascript in mypage.html would look like this:

```
var xmlhttprequest = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:1234/?parameters", true); 
xmlhttp.send();
```

would this work? or will it give a security exception as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a different port does indeed count as cross-site scripting.

There are several well-known ways to make a call (you can always send the data) and use the response (which is what you cannot normally do under anti-xss constraints), including [JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/) and using an iframe in the page to load the data.

Answer (score 5):

This wouldn't go as it is still practically on another server (at least another server instance, which may not be under your control).

You could add a  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yourdomain:1234/ in headers, google for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing. It's relativelly new though, not all browsers know about this.
Or you can use jQuery (read more on http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes).