# Apache can't send request to localhost:8080 (to use Mule Esb Flow)

Tags: rest, esb, mule

I'm trying to use a sample web application that use Ajax to send a request to a php REST service.

I need to use Mule ESB to do this, so i fix my ajax function to send request to ESB on localhost:8080. But the browser said that i can't do this for security reason.

So, there are any way to use mule ESB with a web app (local appache server) locally ?

Comment: Are your static resources served by your apache web server running on port 80?

Comment: all resources is locally using the port 80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to GET a resource from the same host but from a different port is considered cross scripting as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669494/xmlhttprequest-cross-site-scripting-on-same-server-but-differnt-port)

If you want to retrieve it you can:

1. all the option listed at the above link
2. put mule behind a reverse proxy within your apache configuration
3. serve all the content via mule